# how to type hint ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

Tags: python, ctypes, type-hinting

Here is an MRE you can run on `mypy Playground`:

```py
import ctypes
import numpy as np  # type: ignore # (no stubs for numpy)

def np_to_c(arr: np.ndarray) -> tuple[ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.c_int]:
    return arr.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)), ctypes.c_int(len(arr))
```

This type hinting is wrong and according to `mypy`:

```
main.py:4: error: Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
main.py:4: note: Suggestion: use ctypes.POINTER[...] instead of ctypes.POINTER(...)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

but when I do use `ctypes.POINTER[...]` instead of `ctypes.POINTER(...)` (cf screenshot below), I get:

```py
main.py:4: error: Function "ctypes.POINTER" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
main.py:4: note: Perhaps you need "Callable[...]" or a callback protocol?
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=5ef2f50078d01d469c526d86acbb0c93

Answer (score -1):

`ctypes.POINTER` is a constructor that creates an object (a pointer) for the ctypes data type (`c_int`) passed as its argument. So your linter most likely rejects `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)` as a type hint because it is actually a function call.

All objects returned by `ctypes.POINTER` are derived from `ctypes._Pointer`, so my bet would be to use

```py
def np_to_c(arr: np.ndarray) -> tuple[ctypes._Pointer, ctypes.c_int]:
    return arr.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)), ctypes.c_int(len(arr))
```

This, however, doesn't really convey that the returned pointer is specifically for a `c_int` array. Would also be interested in hearing a more informed opinion on this matter!

Comment: `ctypes._Pointer` is generic for type checkers, so the correct hint would be `ctypes._Pointer[ctypes.c_int]`. However, at runtime it's not generic, so `annotations` future-import is necessary (or string annotation). A link to [typeshed definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/b25a5b6aef4b18226a9fd367421ed8ebaaed9528/stdlib/_ctypes.pyi#L76) could also help. Probably the downvote was given for the absence of this important info (not from me).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of the term `generic` in your answer? I'm not sure I understand very well and I'm a bit lost when looking at the typeshet definition.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Sorry, missed your comment. To get started with generics, I'd suggest reading the relevant [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) section. The typeshed definition basically declares a `_Pointer` class that can have one generic parameter, roughly equivalent to its underlying ctype - this parameter can be specified with a subscript (`[]`) notation. However, this is only a .pyi, while actual `_Pointer` at runtime is not generic, so you cannot use this subscript without postponed evaluation.

Comment: Ok, the link was very clear! I understand the notion of generics, but I'm still confused as to why mypy doesn't like that I give it the correct type like I would with `list[int]`?

Comment: The answer must be at the end of your comment, but I'm not sure I understand fully and why `future` helps